# How to flatten a dictionary<string,List<string>> in linq and keep the key in the results

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, flatten

How do you achieve the following in linq?  I feel there should be a Linq alternative.

```
    var foods = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    foods.Add("Cake", new List<string>() { "Sponge", "Gateux", "Tart" });
    foods.Add("Pie", new List<string>() { "Mud", "Apple" });
    foods.Add("Roll", new List<string>() { "Sausage" });

    var result = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    foreach (var food in foods)
    {
        foreach (var detail in food.Value)
        {
            result.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(food.Key, detail));
        }
    }

ie
cake <sponge, gateux>
pie <apple>

to

cake, sponge
cake, gateux
pie,  apple
```

thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var result= foods.SelectMany(f=>f.Value.Select(s=>new Tuple<string, string>(f.Key, s)))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = (from food in foods 
               from detail in food.Value 
               select new Tuple<string, string>(food.Key, detail)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

Linq is a query.  That is what the 'q' stands for.  You are adding items into a dictionary.  Try this

```
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> foods = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()  { 
               {"cake",  new List<string>() {"Sponge", "Gateux", "Tart"}},
               {"Pie",  new List<string>() {"Mud", "Apple"}},
               {"Roll",  new List<string>() {"Sausage"}},
            };
```